# How to add a PushPin item to a map? Windows Phone

Tags: c#, dictionary, toolkit, markers

I'm trying to draw a pushpin to a map in the map page of my application but when I add the code to overlay a pushpin to the map, I get the following errors:

> The type or namespace name `PushPin` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> `Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map` does not contain a definition for `Children` and no extension method `Children` accepting a first argument of type `Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map` could be found

I understand from this that I'm missing a reference? I have references for `controls.maps` and `contols.toolkit`, so I can't understand why.

Also this is the code I'm using to draw the pushpin:

```
PushPin myPin = new Pushpin();
myPin.Location = MyGeoPosition;
myPin.Content = "My car";
MyMap.Children.Add(myPin);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
MapLayer layer1 = new MapLayer();

Pushpin pushpin1 = new Pushpin();

pushpin1.GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition;
pushpin1.Content = "My car";
MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
overlay1.Content = pushpin1;
overlay1.GeoCoordinate = MyGeoPosition;
layer1.Add(overlay1);

myMap.Layers.Add(layer1);
```

You create new overlay for each pushpin, add all overlays to a layer, and add the layer to the map element.

Comment: In my implementation I have extracted this code into a method that takes a string for the pin name and MyGeoPosition, but it appears that if I call this code a second time it overwrites the first. Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: You can remove existing layer with `Map.remove.layers(layer_name)` or empty a layer with `layer_name.Clear()`, but in both cases you need to save the reference for the layer somewhere.

Comment: In my solution I need to save the first layer, ie the first location and then append my second location to that layer.Could you please give an example of how to achieve this or save the layer?

Comment: I think you should open up a new question, provide code and tell what you need. This isn't anymore in scope of this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747011/how-to-save-and-append-to-a-map-layer

Answer (score 0):

You can try..

```
 BitmapImage myImage1; myImage1 = new BitmapImage(new    Uri("/Assets/Images/pushpin-google-hi.png",    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
 var image = new Image(); 
 image.Width = 50; 
 image.Height = 50; 
 image.Opacity = 100; 
 image.Source = myImage1;

 var mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
 mapOverlay.Content = image;
 mapOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(lats, lons);
 var mapLayer = new MapLayer();
 mapLayer.Add(mapOverlay);
 MyMap.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
 MyMap.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(lats, lons), 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First I have this in a utils class:

```
public MapLayer GetCurrentPosition (out MapOverlay myPositionOverlay)
        {
            MapLayer myPositionLayer = new MapLayer();
            myPositionOverlay = new MapOverlay();
            Image myPositionImage = new Image();
            myPositionImage.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/myImagePin.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            myPositionImage.Height = 70;
            myPositionImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            myPositionImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            myPositionOverlay.Content = myPositionImage;
            myPositionLayer.Add(myPositionOverlay);
            return myPositionLayer;
        }
```

Then this goes on your MapLoaded method:

```
MapLayer mypositionArrow = placePushPins.GetCurrentPosition(out myPositionOverlay);
        MyMap.Layers.Add(mypositionArrow);
```

Then, if you want your pushpin not to be static, to move according to your position, add this to your watcher:

```
myPositionOverlay.GeoCoordinate = myCurrentPositionCoordinate;
```

To make the pushpin move smoothly just implement animation like this:  http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/25/part-2-bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-net/